# Modifying documents in memory in yaml-cpp

Tags: c++, yaml-cpp

I want to read a YML document, filter it by modifying some nodes in memory, and then spit it back out with an emitter.  The problem is that YAML::Node appears to be designed to be read-only.  Is there a way to replace a node's value (with a scalar in this case) that I'm missing?

Comment: yaml-cpp doesn't currently support what you're asking for (I'm the author). I'm planning on implementing something like this (or at least a viable workaround), but there are problems to be worked out. (For example, what if you try to replace a sequence with a scalar, and someone else is still holding a reference to one of the sequence elements. Or what if you have `[&a, *a]` and you try to replace `root[0]` by a scalar? Does `root[1]` still alias it?)

Answer (score 0):

What I do with YAML is I read the file and then put the YAML data into my down data structure. Maybe not what you're looking for, but it's one way.

Comment: Yes, that's what I do in my production code.  I'm trying to write a quick test that doesn't rely on those classes though, so I was hoping it was possible to do something quick & dirty.

Comment: Sorry, in that case I don't know.